# JSF2 Phases ApplyValues not called

Tags: jsf-2

We are using JSF2.0 for our application ,we are using QA Load to load testing.

When we submit a jsf form manually ,i can see in the phase listener it is calling all the 6 phases.

But when we do through automation in QALoad tool , we could see only two phases RestoreView and RenderResponse for the same Form submit.

What could be reason ,it skips the other phases Apply Values..process validations...when we do through automation? Is the Http request is not correct.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will happen when it's not a POST request, or when the view state couldn't be restored because there's no view state, or because the session is invalid, or because the session has been expired.

Comment: Yes we made the Form submit without ViewStateID or JSessionID .Is there any other way to make JSF Form submit without passing the viewStateID and JSessison id

Comment: This is related to your previous answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623870/how-can-i-programmatically-upload-a-file-to-a-website

Comment: I have never used QALoad, but you really need to configure it in that tool. I recommend you to ask a directed question about that (leaving JSF outside consideration as it's not JSF's problem). You could also consider to use JMeter instead. It allows you to configure it to take session and hidden fields into account.