# How to Login in a JSF page using java

Tags: java, jsf, post, httpclient

I'm trying to Login in a .jsf intranet page, here is part of it:

```
     <form method="POST" action="j_security_check" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
                <input name="j_username" type="text" class="textbox" maxlength="30"/>
                <input name="j_password" type="password" class="textbox" maxlength="30"/>
                <input type=submit value="Enter" class="button">
                <input type=submit value="Exit" class="button">
    </form>
```

I've searched and tryied something like this at java, but it didn't worked, I get the same page as result:

```
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/login.jsf");   

            List <NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();   
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "92232776"));   
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "(7110oi14)")); 

            UrlEncodedFormEntity sendentity;

            sendentity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, HTTP.UTF_8);

            post.setEntity(sendentity);    
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();   
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, httpContext);   

            System.out.print(convertInputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

(I'm using httpcomponents-client-4.2)

What I need to do to login in this page? is there anything I need to do with the code button "Send"?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The login information is stored in the session. The session is backed by cookies. You need to maintain the cookies across the requests. Basically, you need to pass the retrieved `Set-Cookie` response header back on every subsequent HTTP request in the same session as long as the cookie is valid.

In HttpClient, you need to prepare a [`CookieStore`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) which you set in the [`HttpContext`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html) which you in turn pass on every [`HttpClient#execute()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) call.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
// ...

HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(method1, httpContext);
// ...

HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(method2, httpContext);
// ...
```

Please note that this `j_security_check` login step is not specifically related to JSF, it applies to every other Java Servlet based login form as well. Once you intend to submit a real JSF form as created by `<h:form>`, then you'd need to take a lot more into account. Head to this more detailed answer then: [How can i programmatically upload a file to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623870/how-can-i-programmatically-upload-a-file-to-a-website/8625286#8625286) Whilst this treats uploading of a file programmatically through a JSF form, the basic principles for submitting a JSF form are the same (certain hidden input fields have to be taken account with and so on).

Comment: Why didn't you tell about that exception? That's completely unrelated to the login task. The `NullPointerException` just means that you're trying to access or invoke a reference which is `null`. The fix is quite simple: just make sure that it's not `null`, or do a `if` check for `null` and then bypass it.

Comment: I'm getting the same login page as answer, even using cookies while executing the http'srequest...  do you know what it could be?  (no more nullpointer =D )