# No stored conversation in JBoss 7.1.1, Seam 2.3.0

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, seam, jboss7.x

When I click `<p:commandLink>` it cannot restore a conversation that has already begun.
I use JBoss 7.1.1, Seam 2.3.0 + Primefaces 3

Log output before rendering my page `dashboard.xhml`

```
11:06:35,803 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "MRBS.war"
11:06:37,323 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,323 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization] Using Java + Groovy hot deploy

11:06:37,334 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,334 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from servlet context: jndi:/default-host/MRBS/view/
login.page.xml

11:06:37,337 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,337 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from servlet context: jndi:/default-host/MRBS/WEB-I
NF/pages.xml

11:06:37,347 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,346 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle] Session started

11:06:37,348 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,348 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.identity

11:06:37,350 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,350 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

11:06:37,351 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,351 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

11:06:37,352 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,352 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

11:06:37,353 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,353 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.security.ruleBasedPermissionResolver

11:06:37,370 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,370 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

11:06:37,454 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,454 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.drools.RuleBase] parsing rules: /security.drl

11:06:37,459 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,459 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: security.drl

11:06:37,652 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,652 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] starting up: org.jboss.seam.web.session

11:06:37,653 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,653 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.core.events

11:06:37,664 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,664 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.FacesLifecycle] >>> Begin JSF request for /MRBS/view/dashboard.seam

11:06:37,666 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,666 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Naming] JNDI InitialContext properties:{}

11:06:37,668 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,668 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] beginning transaction prior to phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

11:06:37,669 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,669 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] beginning JTA transaction

11:06:37,701 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,701 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

11:06:37,702 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,702 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] Page Context will be lazilly created

11:06:37,704 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,704 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.core.Manager] No stored conversation

11:06:37,709 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,709 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: vfs:/C:/Java/JBoss-7.1.1/
standalone/deployments/MRBS.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug.jar/META-INF/resources/debug.xhtml

11:06:37,712 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,712 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: vfs:/C:/Java/JBoss-7.1.1/
standalone/deployments/MRBS.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug.jar/META-INF/resources/debug.xhtml

11:06:37,714 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,714 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] committing transaction after phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

11:06:37,715 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,714 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] committing JTA transaction

11:06:37,716 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,716 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: vfs:/C:/Java/JBoss-7.1.1/
standalone/deployments/MRBS.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug.jar/META-INF/resources/debug.xhtml

11:06:37,717 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,717 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] beginning transaction prior to phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6

11:06:37,718 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,718 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] beginning JTA transaction

11:06:37,719 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,719 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: vfs:/C:/Java/JBoss-7.1.1/
standalone/deployments/MRBS.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug.jar/META-INF/resources/debug.xhtml

11:06:37,731 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,730 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.core.Manager] Beginning long-running conversation

11:06:37,734 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,733 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] committing transaction after invoking page actions

11:06:37,734 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,734 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] committing JTA transaction

11:06:37,735 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,735 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] beginning transaction before continuing render

11:06:37,736 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,736 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] beginning JTA transaction

11:06:37,739 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:37,738 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernatePersistenceProvider] Hibernate Search not present

11:06:37,739 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.search.Version from [Module "deployment.MRBS.war:main" from Service Mo
dule Loader]

11:06:37,740 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

11:06:37,741 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)

11:06:37,742 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)

11:06:37,743 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)

11:06:37,743 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)

11:06:37,744 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)

11:06:37,745 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

11:06:37,745 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,746 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernatePersistenceProvider.<clinit>(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)

11:06:37,747 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

11:06:37,748 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,748 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,749 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,750 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,750 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)

11:06:37,751 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateJavaBean(Component.java:1445)

11:06:37,751 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1364)

11:06:37,752 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2186)

11:06:37,753 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2034)

11:06:37,753 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2013)

11:06:37,754 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2007)

11:06:37,755 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1980)

11:06:37,755 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1975)

11:06:37,756 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.persistence.PersistenceProvider.instance(PersistenceProvider.java:204)

11:06:37,757 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.persistence.PersistenceContexts.beforeRender(PersistenceContexts.java:140)

11:06:37,757 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:500)

11:06:37,758 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:147)

11:06:37,759 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:117)

11:06:37,759 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)

11:06:37,760 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)

11:06:37,761 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)

11:06:37,761 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

11:06:37,762 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

11:06:37,763 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:37,764 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)

11:06:37,764 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)

11:06:37,765 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,766 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)

11:06:37,767 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,767 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)

11:06:37,768 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,769 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)

11:06:37,769 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,770 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)

11:06:37,771 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,771 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)

11:06:37,772 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)

11:06:37,773 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)

11:06:37,773 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)

11:06:37,774 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:37,775 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

11:06:37,775 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:06:37,776 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)

11:06:37,777 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

11:06:37,778 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:06:37,778 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:06:37,779 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:06:37,780 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:06:37,781 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:06:37,781 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

11:06:37,782 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

11:06:37,783 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:06:37,783 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

11:06:38,542 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) image attribute is deprecated to define an icon, use icon attribute inst
ead.
11:06:38,543 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) image attribute is deprecated to define an icon, use icon attribute inst
ead.
11:06:38,546 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) image attribute is deprecated to define an icon, use icon attribute inst
ead.
11:06:38,547 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) image attribute is deprecated to define an icon, use icon attribute inst
ead.
11:06:40,582 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,582 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] committing transaction after phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6

11:06:40,584 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,584 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] committing JTA transaction

11:06:40,585 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,585 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.core.Manager] Storing conversation state: 1

11:06:40,586 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,586 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.FacesLifecycle] After render response, destroying contexts

11:06:40,587 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,587 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying business process context

11:06:40,589 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,589 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] flushing server-side conversation context

11:06:40,590 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,590 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] flushing session context

11:06:40,592 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,592 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying event context

11:06:40,593 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,593 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.core.conversationPropagation

11:06:40,594 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,594 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.transaction.transaction

11:06:40,595 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,595 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextFactoryImpl_KEY

11:06:40,596 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,596 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.core.manager

11:06:40,597 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,597 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.transaction.synchronizations

11:06:40,598 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,598 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.web.servletContexts

11:06:40,599 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,599 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.web.requestContextPath

11:06:40,600 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,600 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.core.events

11:06:40,601 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,601 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.jboss.seam.web.requestServletPath

11:06:40,601 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,601 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] destroying: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestConte
xtListener.REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES

11:06:40,602 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 11:06:40,602 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.FacesLifecycle] <<< End JSF request for /MRBS/view/dashboard.seam
```

Error when I click `<p:commandLink>`

```
10:59:09,038 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,038 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization] Using Java + Groovy hot deploy

10:59:09,049 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,049 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from servlet context: jndi:/default-host/MRBS/view/
login.page.xml

10:59:09,052 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,052 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from servlet context: jndi:/default-host/MRBS/WEB-I
NF/pages.xml

10:59:09,057 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,057 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.FacesLifecycle] >>> Begin JSF request for /MRBS/view/dashboard.seam

10:59:09,060 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,060 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener] beginning transaction prior to phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1

10:59:09,062 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,062 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction] beginning JTA transaction

10:59:09,079 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,079 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] isPageContextActive is null

10:59:09,080 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,080 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts] Page Context will be lazilly created

10:59:09,081 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,081 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.core.Manager] No stored conversation

10:59:09,085 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 10:59:09,085 DEBUG [org.jboss.seam.util.Resources] Loaded resource from context classloader: vfs:/C:/Java/JBoss-7.1.1/
standalone/deployments/MRBS.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug.jar/META-INF/resources/debug.xhtml

10:59:09,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as.txn] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBAS010152: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 1
```

dashboard.xhtml

```
 <h:form id="datePickerForm">   
    <p:commandLink action="#{DashBoard.nextWeek()}" update="datePanelGrid" ajax="true" vale="Next Week"/>

        <h:panelGroup id="datePanelGrid">
            <h:outputText value="#{DashBoard.startDate}" style="color:#333333;font-size:15px;">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            </h:outputText>
            -
            <h:outputText value="#{DashBoard.endDate}" style="color:#333333;font-size:15px;">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            </h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
 </h:form>
```

DashBoard.java

```
@Name("DashBoard")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class DashBoard extends BaseBean {
    private boolean initFlag = true;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public boolean getInitFlag() {
        return initFlag;
    }

    @Begin(nested = true)
    public void init() {
        initFlag = false;
        startDate = new Date();
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
        cal.setTime(loadEndDate(startDate));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); 
        endDate =  cal.getTime();
        return endDate;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;            
    }

    public void nextWeek() {
        startDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen PrimeFaces behave oddly with AJAX requests and transactions. I honestly don't know where the issue is. You could try w/o PrimeFaces and see if that works. If the problem persists we know it's not PrimeFaces at least.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Conversation need to be restored by request (ajax/non ajax) parameter, for JSF it is  **javax.faces.ViewState**, see also: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175763/how-to-send-post-request-to-jsf-component-without-using-html-form). 
You need to check request parameters (firebug or something) and primefaces doc (not much aware of this).