# Replicating JSP/JSF/IceFaces requests for scraping purposes

Tags: c#, jsf, web-scraping, restsharp, icefaces

I am trying to scrape some data off an enterprise website that was made using JSF and IceFaces. I am using C# and the RestSharp library.

I have no experience with JSP , JSF or IceFaces at all, so I am just trying to figure out how to replicate what the site is doing using HTTP requests but I wasn't very successful. The site does not have any concept of routing whatsoever (and when you accidentally happen to press the back button in the browser, you are logged out...).

What I have managed to do so far:

- Make a POST request with credentials to `/login` resource in order to log in
- Retrieve JSESSIONID Cookie after login and store it to my `CookieContainer`
- Use Regexes to get the `ice.session` and `ice.view` values
- Replicate a POST request to the `block/send-receive-updates`

If the original POST request is managed by the JS code on the site (When I am clicking around), it returns an XML response like this:

```
<updates>
    <update address="some form id" tag="table"> ... </update>
    <update address="content" tag="div"> ... </update>
    <update address="The ice.session id, the ice.view number separated with : followed by the string 'dynamic-code'" tag="script"> ... </update>
</updates>
```

However, I took all the encoded POST params that this request is doing on the site and replicated them in my C# code and my response only has the last update (script tag) like this:

```
<updates>
    <update address="The ice.session id, the ice.view number separated with : followed by the string 'dynamic-code'" tag="script"> ... </update>
</updates>
```

Does anyone please have experience with scraping/testing these technologies and can help me figure out what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12175763

Comment: Yeah I have read something similar before, but it's not that helpful. I am replicating the exact same parameters that I can see the site do when clicking on buttons. There's no `javax.faces.ViewState` passed, only `ice.view` and the initial page also doesn't contain `javax.faces.ViewState` so I think maybe that part is done differently with IceFaces (probably with `ice.view`)

Comment: Older ICEfaces versions have indeed a proprietary ajax engine instead of a standard JSF one. Well, I've never really used ICEfaces myself, so it's only guessing. I know they have kind of decent "JavaScript disabled" fallback, so try simulating/tracking that instead of focusing on ajax request-response payload in a regular webbrowser which you won't ever properly simulate with merely a HTTP client (you basically need a HTML/JS client for that).

Comment: It says `Javascript is blocked. ICEfaces cannot run.`. By HTML client, you mean that I would have to use something like PhantomJS or Selenium or things like that, that actually run a browser?