# Not able to upload file using HttpClient POST request

Tags: java, http, post, file-upload, httpclient

I have a JSP page(/Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp) which has a form and a input file type File uploader. On clicking on Upload button the form gets submitted to self URL /Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp and the files gets uploaded. I want to automate this file upload, and hence I am using HttpClient API to pick up the file and submit the form. I am trying upload a CSV file by POST request using HttpClient APIs but somehow the file is not getting uploaded. Here is the code snippet which does the upload:

```
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9088/Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp");
        httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+ sessionId);
        String boundary = "---------------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
        
        File file = new File("C:\\root\\projects\\DataSources1.csv");
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file); 
        StringBody importBody = new StringBody("Import", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody csvImportFormBody = new StringBody("csvImportForm", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody uniqueTokenBody = new StringBody("j911", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        StringBody uniqueViewBody = new StringBody("j911", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.setBoundary(boundary);
        multipartEntity.addPart("uploadFileName", fileBody);
        multipartEntity.addPart("csvimportForm:ImportButton", importBody);
        multipartEntity.addPart("csvImportForm", csvImportFormBody);
        multipartEntity.addPart("uniqueToken", uniqueTokenBody);
        multipartEntity.addPart("uniqueView", uniqueViewBody);

        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
```

The original HTML form which I want to simulate in java code is:

```
<form id="csvImportForm" method="post" action="/Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" class="trayheader">
            <!-- "File Name" (label) --> <span id="csvImportForm:fileNameTitleId">File Name:</span></td>
        <td width="50%">
            <!-- File Selection (input) --> <input type="file" name="uploadFileName" style="width: 90%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
            <!-- Import (button) --> <input type="submit" value="Import" name="csvImportForm:importButton" id="csvImportForm:importButton" onclick="javascript:hideForm();" class="commandExButton" /></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="csvImportForm" value="csvImportForm" /><input type="hidden" name="csvImportForm:_idcl" /><input type="hidden" name="clickedLogoutLink" />
</form>
```

Can anyone give any hints why the file is not getting uploaded? When I execute the code, it just fetches the jsp page and does not upload the file.

**UPDATE after comparing the HEADERS and POST PARAMETERS:**
Compared both the headers and parameters.
With the FORM it is:

```
Request               POST /Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Referer                https://host1:30862/Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp
Accept-Language             en-GB
User-Agent         Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e0212b90428
Accept-Encoding              gzip, deflate
Host       host1:30862
Content-Length                2398
DNT       1
Connection        Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  ssoLang=en; dbihybrid_preferredLanguage=en; dbihybrid_locationDepartment=in.false; wt_eid=2143773288100110717; JSESSIONID=W9vmLJRZkf7u2Pevmd4QdSC2hUvliVepaVm-tFuz9m7O4lkWYPUw!1008091679; PA.MinLogLevel=30
```

AND with HTTPClient it is:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9C_m5OE8QUquA9sdj4T5eOyVS1yXC6yb0jdiVCuaZ_X-MjPQqEMw!1008091679
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1459867674444
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Referrer: https://host1:30862/Test/faces/pages/admin/csvImport.jsp
Content-Length: 2423
Host: host1:30862
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

The POST parameters with FORM:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm" value="csvImportForm"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uniqueToken" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uniqueView" value="j1154"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm:importStatus" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clipboard_l" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clipboard_t" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFileName"; filename="C:\Users\Public\Documents\eclipse luna\workspace\WebScraper\properties\DataSources.csv" Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm:importButton" value="Import"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="3514046226787645214:-6068281828613739341"
```

The POST parameters with HttpClient:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFileName"; filename="C:\Users\Public\Documents\eclipse luna\workspace\WebScraper\properties\DataSources.csv" Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm:importButton" value="Import"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm" value="csvImportForm"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uniqueToken" value="j1228"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uniqueView" value="j1228"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="8959970480121731339:-7418251671370896640"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clipboard_l" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="clipboard_t" value=""
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csvImportForm:importStatus" value=""
```

Comment: In browser while submitting use the developer tools to see the http post. In your application use a proxy (e.g.TCP/IP monitor in views in eclipse) to see the message being sent. Compare both and you will have your answer.

Comment: I did the comparison, and I have added the results as an update above. No clue whatsoever, why its not working.

Comment: Why is the content length different? Please try to compare post data also. Is this page secured?

Comment: I referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623870/how-can-i-programmatically-upload-a-file-to-a-website/8625286#8625286 and found that one POST parameter was wrongly named. After correcting the error, it started working in HTTP. But when I put the same code on HTTPS, it is still not submitting the form. I have added an additional hidden parameter javax.faces.ViewState. Is there something special we need to do when dealing with HTTPS?

Comment: I have added headers for POST parameters for Secure call in the post. @sashwat, do you have any hints. The difference in length was because I was trying to upload different files. For HTTPS, the length is almost same.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the problem in your case, but `MultipartEntityBuilder` handles the *Content-Type* header and boundary internally so you do not have to set them explicitly. That is, you can safely remove the following lines

```
    String boundary = "---------------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
```

otherwise they might conflict each other.

Since you are just setting boundary to something random, you can just let `MultipartEntityBuilder` do it for you. This is the default behavior if you to not provide a boundary. And you can therefor also remove

```
    multipartEntity.setBoundary(boundary);
```

Comment: I removed it but that did not help. thanks for the response.